# CakePHP and Lightview JQuery Plugin: Increment View Count

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am using the following plugin in my webpage:

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/

The script works great in terms of displaying the photos and everything else it is supposed to do, however, I would like to accomplish the following I havent been able to:

```
Have the plugin increment view count everytime an image is displayed
```

I have created the following action in my `photo.php` model, but I can't figure out a way to call using the Plugin:

```
function incrementViewCount($id) {
    $this->updateAll(
        array('Photo.viewed' => 'Photo.viewed+1'),                    
        array('Photo.id' => $id)
    );

}
```

I have it setup per the following on my site:

```
<?php
    foreach ($photocategory['Photo'] as $photo){
?>
<li>
<a 
        href="/img/uploads/photos/<?php echo photo['photocategory_id']."/".$photo['image']; ?>" 
        class="lightview" 
        data-lightview-group="shared_options"
    >
    <img 
            style="width:155px;height:113px;" 
            src="/img/uploads/photos/<?php echo $photo['photocategory_id']."/thumb/".$photo['image']; ?>" 
            alt="" 
    />
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

If anyone knows anything about this plugin or jQuery and if you can suggest a way to accomplish this, it would be great!

Comment: the site you pointed to seems recomed to use version3 
http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/

Comment: it looks like callback afterUpdate: is what is your search for, add to it ajax request that will tell server that you saw  image

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've read about afterUpdate, but I havent yet figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CakePHP this
https://github.com/sliker/CakePHP-Counter-Plugin may help.

Has simple call methods for incrementing counter.